# Why this return me 'string given' when the only Id pass is an int

Tags: php, symfony, events

I'm new on symfony and need help

When i'm running 'console debug:event' I got this error message :

```
 App\EventListener\ReservationEventSubscriber::__construct(): Argument #3 ($id) must be of type int, string given, called in /Applica  
  tions/MAMP/htdocs/E-STock/E-STock_v6/var/cache/dev/ContainerTiaj2qn/getReservationEventSubscriberService.php on line 22
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to fix it.
Even I'm not sur to really understand the problem ^^

this is my code :

ReservationEventSubscriber :

```
class ReservationEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $manager;
    private int $id;


    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, int $pieceId)
    {
        
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->id = $pieceId;
    }
```

I've bind my "pieceId" here on 'service.yaml'

```
parameters:
      id: 'secret'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
           int $pieceId: '%id%'

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

Comment: Under parameters your `id: 'secret'` is a string.. It is expecting `id: 69` for example..

Comment: Ok but If I put 'id: 69' will my id always be 69 or is it just to define the type ?

Comment: Yes it will always be that, things set in your service.yaml file shouldn't change. As it is a subscriber, If you are trying to get the ID of whatever, then you can probably get this from the actual event. I can't say anymore about this as i don't know how your *ReservationEventSubscriber* works..

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter id is string in  'service.yaml' and you set the property type of $id in ReservationEventSubscriber to be integer. `private int $id;`

Just set the id in service.yaml to be interer, for example:

```
parameters:
      id: 5
```